# How to create jobs and bridges on a chainlink node using CLI

Tags: chainlink

I am trying out all the CLI commands on a chainlink node. The main motivation is to execute these commands as bash scripts with chainlink node CLI. I have been unsuccessful in executing the two main commands which are as follows:

- create a job on the node using `chainlink jobs create --file`
- create a bridge to an external adapter using `chainlink bridges create --file`

I run the commands using the following syntax:
`docker exec -it chainlink /bin/bash -c "cmd1, cmd2"`

I have created `bridge.json` and `job.toml` files and provide them with `--file` flag in the CLI commands. Also, I have tried positioning them in the `root` and in the `chainlink` directory and tried providing the JSON  and TOML as raw input with the commands.

The errors I get are:

- `invalid JSON or file not found`
- `Incorrect Usage: flag provided but not defined: -f` with `Error running app`

Please help me with the correct syntax needed to create a job and bridge on a chainlink node using the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to create jobs/bridges etc using files that contain the details of what you want to create, you use the syntax as follows. Note this will create a job using the TOML found in the a.toml file in the root of the chainlink node directory:

```
./chainlink jobs create a.toml
```

Comment: 1-do I have to restart the node.
2- Is there a way to provide the file using a bash script that consumes an external file.

we are trying to figure out if we can create a job/bridge from input provided by an external client.

Comment: no you should not have to restart the node. If you want to create a job and bridge from an external client, suggest looking to see if you can use the API. The node has an API that is no longer documented, am not 100% sure if its still active or not (assume it is), but if you go back to previous versions of the docs you can see the endpoints. Node some may have changed (you would need to check the node code) https://web.archive.org/web/20191214183216/https://docs.chain.link/reference

Comment: Thanks, Harry.
The APIs are working and are suitable for our use case. Just one clarification, will this work for job specs that are written in TOML format.

Comment: yes it should work for TOML format jobs too